# Hive complex data types using Hive CLI

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am new to `Hadoop` and `Big Data`. I have got `Hive` version `Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.4.0`
.Facing some basic problems with creating complex data types in `HIVE` tables now. I have a customer table which is created as :

```
create external table if not exists  customer_details1 (customerId string, mobileNumber string, address ARRAY <STRUCT<houseNo:string,street1:string>>);
```

I will want to `push data` into this table using `INSERT statements`.  Can some one tell me how to push a dummy record into this table using `command prompt` ? 
I do not want to push data into this using an external file (LOAD DATA).

Please can some one help me?

Comment: Which version of Hive are you using?

Comment: since you mentioned dummy data , you could insert into table select '','','' from someother table;

Comment: let me know if u need detaild expalination on loading dummy data using insert statement

Comment: Could you provide with an example to insert into a struct array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually an **external** table is just a wrapper that enables Hive to *read* from flat files.

If you want to *load* data into a Hive table (as in LOAD-INSERT or INSERT-SELECT) you should consider a **managed** table. It would use Sequence format by default but you may opt for Orc, Text, Avro, whatever.

If you want to run *atomic inserts* (as in INSERT-VALUES) you need Hive V0.14+ plus a managed table with **transaction support** => requires Orc with bucketing, periodic compactions in the background, etc etc

If you feel up to that challenge, reading the documentation could prove useful e.g. [Inserting values into tables from SQL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Writingdataintothefilesystemfromqueries) and [Hive Transactions rationale](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions)

Comment: I have tried to move my table to hbase now and things are working better. Could you please guide me how I can update an external table using hive? I am trying to reference hbase table in hive ( hbase hive intrgration)

Comment: AFAIK the Hive-HBase integration is designed for batch reads (using HBase "scan" from multiple MapReduce tasks in parallel). Can also be used for bulk loading (building a new HFile offline, then "mounting" it in HBase).

Comment: Afterthought: if what you want is to script atomic "put" / "get" operations, the HBase shell may be the best fit. Or maybe the StarGate REST server if you need remote access.

Answer (score 1):

Creating table in Hive:

```
create table if not exists mytable1 (id int, name string, address array<struct<street : string, town : string>>) comment 'my practice table' ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

I think simple insert query are not supported by Hive currently.

[Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980773/insert-data-into-hive-table)

Comment: With struct in the table I was able to insert into the table with insert query :

 insert into table customer_details SELECT '101','+96597795541', named_struct('houseNo',houseNo,'street1',street1) from address;


But when it is a ARRAY <STRUCT<>> This would not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As @Samson Scharfrichter has mentioned, atomic insertion of array structures might not be possible to hive tables. And I have decided to move my tables to hbase to support the flexibility of adding columns on write. Thanks for all the suggestions and guidelines.